# Hibernate Jpa: update on @Embeddable table generates a query using the wrong table which @Embedded

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have the database tables `Person` and `Details`.
`Details` are intended to carry the miscellaneous fields for the `Person` using the foreign key `PERSON_ID`.

JPA code has the following equivalent java classes,

```java
@Entity
public class Person{

    /**
    other fields 
    **/ 

   @Embedded
   private Details details;

}

@Embeddable
public class Details{
    /**
    own fields
    **/

}
```

I am able to read the `Details` corresponding to the `Person` using hibernate/JPA code.

But when I try to update the fields in the `Details` table, hibernate generates the update query on the `Person` table instead of the `Details` table.

Comment: It is because `@Entity` annotaion is create `Person` table in your database and `Details` is just normal class which is embedded with `Person` entity.

Comment: But I am trying to represent the database tables with the same name in my java classes. Can the @Embeddable class represent a database table?

Comment: Embeddable is not create new table in database but Embeddable is used when you have two or more primary key in single table.